# Cannot merge Income table and Outcome table with full outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-outer-join

I have 2 tables: `Income` (`InvoiceDate, TotalAmount`) and `Outcome` (`ExpenseDate, TotalAmount`).

Suppose that I have data for each column as below:

`Income`:

```
| INVOICEDATE | TOTALAMOUNT |
|-------------|-------------|
|  2013-10-16 |       22000 |
|  2013-10-17 |       14400 |
|  2013-10-18 |        4488 |
```

`Outcome`:

```
| EXPENSEDATE | TOTALAMOUNT |
|-------------|-------------|
|  2013-10-25 |          15 |
```

I want to merge these 2 tables to show as below:

```
|       DATE | INCOME | OUTCOME |
|------------|--------|---------|
| 2013-10-25 |      0 |      15 |
| 2013-10-16 |  22000 |       0 |
| 2013-10-17 |  14400 |       0 |
| 2013-10-18 |   4488 |       0 |
```

However when I run my T-SQL, It will show like this instead:

```
|       DATE | INCOME | OUTCOME |
|------------|--------|---------|
|     (null) | (null) |      15 |
| 2013-10-16 |  22000 |  (null) |
| 2013-10-17 |  14400 |  (null) |
| 2013-10-18 |   4488 |  (null) |
```

This is my T-SQL:

```
SELECT
    CASE (income.InvoiceDate)
       WHEN NULL THEN Outcome.expenseDate
       ELSE income.InvoiceDate
    END AS [Date],
    CASE (income.TotalAmount)
       WHEN NULL THEN 0
       ELSE income.TotalAmount
    END AS Income,
    CASE (Outcome.TotalAmount)
        WHEN NULL THEN 0
        ELSE Outcome.TotalAmount
    END AS Outcome
FROM
    Outcome
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    income ON Outcome.expenseDate = income.InvoiceDate
WHERE
    NOT (
        Outcome.TotalAmount = 0
        AND income.TotalAmount = 0
    )
```

You can test this SQL at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3589f/1

Does anyone know what's wrong with my T-SQL?

Thank You!
Pengan

Answer (score 0):

You may want a `union` instead

```
select InvoiceDate as Date, TotalAmount as Income, 0 as Outcome from Income
union all
select ExpenseDate, 0, TotalAmount from Outcome
```

If you can have income and expenses on the same date, you can group them from this.

```
select [date], Sum(Income), Sum(outcome) from
(
    select InvoiceDate as Date, TotalAmount as Income, 0 as Outcome from Income
    union all
    select ExpenseDate, 0, TotalAmount from Outcome
) v
group by [date]
```

As to what is wrong with your statement, the problem is with the `case`.
They should use `is null` rather than `when null`

```
CASE WHEN income.TotalAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE income.TotalAmount end,
```

But a shorter way is to use `ISNULL`

```
ISNULL(income.TotalAmount, 0)
```

Comment: This could potentially give two lines if the same date appears as an income and an outcome. I wonder if this is a valid usecase under the OP's conditions. If it isn't, this would work brilliantly (and probably faster than my solution).

Comment: @Mureinik I wondered the same myself. I've edited the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` statement is a shorthand for a series of `=` operators. However, `NULL` is **never** equal to any value (that's what the `IS` operator is for), so using `CASE` to evaluate `NULL`s is somewhat pointless.

Instead, you can yse the [`COALESCE` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to replace your `NULL`s with 0s as following:

```
SELECT Outcome.expenseDate AS [Date],
       COALESCE(Income.TotalAMount, 0) AS Income,
       COALESCE(Outcome.TotalAMount, 0) AS Outcome
FROM   Outcome
FULL OUTER JOIN income ON Outcome.expenseDate = income.InvoiceDate
WHERE   NOT (
    Outcome.TotalAmount = 0
    AND income.TotalAmount = 0
)
```